# how to set column in GridView to default value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, default-value

I have a column in a GridView called Qty Advised and this column needs to be defaulted to 1. But every time the GridView loads it displays 0 in the column. I set the default value in the database to 1 and set `SerNo.QtyAdvised = 1;` in the `ItemDataBound` function but it still displays 0.

Is there a way to set the default here?

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="QtyAdvised" HeaderText="Qty Advised" ></asp:BoundField>
```

I don't understand how it keeps displaying 0
The GridView is created dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by setting the default in the code for the database

```
public int _QtyAdvised = 1;
public int QtyAdvised
        {
            get { return _QtyAdvised; }
            set { _QtyAdvised = value; }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

May be you need to use `DataColumn.DefaultValue` Property.

It sets the default value for the column when you are creating new rows.

Reference: [DataColumn.DefaultValue Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue.aspx)

**OR**

alternatively on rowdatabound, you can set column default value

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Checking the RowType of the Row  
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "1"; // Use your column index here
    }  
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, but since MSDN only provides an example for VB, perhaps you could provide an example with C# for additional clarity.

Comment: I am creating this GridView dynamically so I don't have any create column code

Comment: You should consider creating a Defaults configuration class  if there will be a lot of default values. At least in the future if you end up changing the default value and its somewhere else, then you will just have to change it in one place.